# meaning of the phrase "amped up on" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, register

It is from [Crash Course A&P](https://youtu.be/rd2cf5hValM). It is at 1 minute and 23 second. Here is the context:

> But even when they are functioming well, some of your immune cells are careening around your body like miniature, biological versions of Mad Max war boys. **Amped up on** signalling chemicals, scouring the terrain for hostiles, and covered from top to bottom in the dismembered parts of the enemies that they have vanquished.

Does that mean that they got energetic because of the signalling chemicals, or because they increased the amount of the signalling chemicals?

Comment: To be **amped (up) on {a chemical substance}** is slang for being full of drugs that excite the nervous system, like turning the dial on the sound system **amp**lifier up to 10.

Comment: Compare "to be **high on** cocaine".  "high" is the adjective denoting the state, and the object of preposition "on" is the substance that induced that state.  "amped up" is the adjectival phrase (formed from the past participle of the verb **to amp {something} up with {substance}**).   *The horse doctor amped up the thoroughbred  with performance-enhancing drugs before the big race.*

Comment: or *.... **amped** the thoroughbred **up** with performance-enhancing drugs...*